# Getting datarow values into a string?

Tags: c#, ado.net, datarow

I have a dataset called "results" with several rows of data.  I'd like to get this data into a string, but I can't quite figure out how to do it.  I'm using the below code:

```
string output = "";
foreach (DataRow rows in results.Tables[0].Rows)     
{
    output = output + rows.ToString() + "\n";
}
```

However, I think I'm missing something because this isn't working.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting an exception somewhere?

Comment: No exception.  It's just that the value of "output" isn't at all what I was expecting.  But, I think the two answers below have me headed towards the right solution.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to specify which column of the datarow you want to pull data from.

Try the following:

```
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataRow rows in results.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in results.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                output.AppendFormat("{0} ", rows[col]);
            }

            output.AppendLine();
        }
```

Comment: Jeff, this worked perfectly!  Thank you so much!  I haven't used StringBuilder much, at all, so I'm glad to have the opportunity to put it to use here.  Thanks for the example code, too!

Comment: You're very welcome, StringBuilder is awesome.  Get used to using it whenever you find yourself manipulating a string many times.

Answer (score 34):

I've done this a lot myself. If you just need a comma separated list for all of row values you can do this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in results.Tables[0].Rows)     
{
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
}
```

A StringBuilder is the preferred method as string concatenation is significantly slower for large amounts of data.

Answer (score 8):

You can get a columns value by doing this

```
 rows["ColumnName"]
```

You will also have to cast to the appropriate type.

```
 output += (string)rows["ColumnName"]
```

Comment: Thanks, Matthew.  Both you and Andrei were correct about needing to get my values from the column for each row.  I'd totally forgotten about that.

Answer (score 4):

Your `rows` object holds an `Item` attribute where you can find the values for each of your columns. You can not expect the columns to concatenate themselves when you do a `.ToString()` on the row.
You should access each column from the row separately, use a `for` or a `foreach` to walk the array of columns.

Here, take a look at the class:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx

Comment: You are right, Andrei.  I'd forgotten that I'd have to iterate over the columns in the rows as well.

Answer (score 1):

**How about some love in LinQ?**

If you wan't it on `List<string>`

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];

List<string> outputs = dt.Select().Select(x => x.ItemArray[0].ToString()).ToList();
```

and if just single `string`

```
string output = string.Join(",", outputs);
```

Sometimes i'm reusing the data in different format. this is what i usually do.